# Why Spring JPA / Hibernate is returning 0 when updating?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this query and it returns 0 instead of 1 even though it updates one row.
This is the code I have:

```
@Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Tshirt SET smallSizeInStock = smallSizeInStock - :quantityBoughtByUser WHERE id = :productId and (smallSizeInStock - :quantityBoughtByUser) >= 0")
    int updateSmallQuantityInStock(@Param("quantityBoughtByUser") int quantityBoughtByUser, @Param("productId")Long productId);
```

This is how I call it:

```
   int rowsUpdated = tshirtProductRepository.updateSmallQuantityInStock(productCart.getQuantity().intValue(), productId);
```

Then I have this code to rollback if no row was updated:

```
if (rowsUpdated == 0) {
            throw new AppException("The tshirt quantity you tried to buy for the product "
                    + productCart.getProductDTO().getName() + " is not available.");
        }
```

The thing is it return 0, even though I can see the row being updated. And I see it reflected on the database. If I remove the if statement everything works fine, but I need to rollback when no row was updated at this step.

This is what I get on my console when I updates:

```
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 DEBUG 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update products set updated_at=?, category_id=?, deleted_at=?, description=?, in_stock=?, name=?, notify_low_stock=?, promotion_price=?, quantity_in_stock=?, quantity_sold=?, regular_price=?, short_description=?, sku=?, store_id=?, weight=? where id=?
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Sun Sep 02 18:43:13 UTC 2018]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [This is my big description]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [BOOLEAN] - [false]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [My New Product]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [BOOLEAN] - [true]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [8] as [DOUBLE] - [799.99]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.571 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [9] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [10] as [INTEGER] - [0]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [11] as [DOUBLE] - [899.99]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [12] as [VARCHAR] - [This is my short description]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [13] as [VARCHAR] - [ABC-DEF]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [14] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [15] as [DOUBLE] - [50.0]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.572 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [16] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 DEBUG 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update tshirts set extra_large_size_in_stock=?, large_size_in_stock=?, medium_size_in_stock=?, small_size_in_stock=?, unique_size_in_stock=? where id=?
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - [-11]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [null]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.573 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.574 DEBUG 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create temporary  table HT_tshirts (id int8 not null) 
2018-09-02 11:43:13.575 DEBUG 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into HT_tshirts select tshirt0_.id as id from tshirts tshirt0_ inner join products tshirt0_1_ on tshirt0_.id=tshirt0_1_.id where tshirt0_.id=? and tshirt0_.small_size_in_stock-?>=0
2018-09-02 11:43:13.575 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.575 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [7]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.576 DEBUG 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update tshirts set small_size_in_stock=small_size_in_stock-? where (id) IN (select id from HT_tshirts)
2018-09-02 11:43:13.576 TRACE 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [7]
2018-09-02 11:43:13.577 DEBUG 23328 --- [nio-5000-exec-8] org.hibernate.SQL                        : drop table HT_tshirts
```

My TShirt Object extends Product and they share the same ID.

Update:
So before calling the update method I had a retrieve method being called. 
If I remove the retrieve, then the update one works just fine. I'm wondering why that happens.

Comment: Strange. Could you provide an example project that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Please check my [demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sd-insert-update-delete-demo) with custom insert/update/delete operations - all works as expected (SB 2.0.4).

Comment: @Cepr0 - Thank you for that. I saw your example and I tried creating a native query, but still getting 0 rows updated. Jens, I don't have an example project that reproduces this issue. I'll try to get that and will post it